# Amazon DVD details Web Scraping not able to pick the required Element

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I passing EAN numbers of the certain movies and extracting movie name and ASIN number in Amazon.
"[https://www.amazon.de/s?k=7321925005738&__mk_de_DE=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&ref=nb_sb_noss](https://www.amazon.de/s?k=7321925005738&__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss)"

But in Amazon website,i face problem like some time the search results contains Sponsored product result also (It may or may not come),How ever i want to extract other than Sponsored products.

So when ever i debug.print the Amazon ASIN number and Movie name,it prints all the ASIN number and movie name (Which includes sponsored product).

For identifying the sponsored product,the way i am using is data-component-type="sp-sponsored-result"
in the response text,

where as actual product does not contain this id at "data-component-type" all,so i am not able to separate the actual movie name (Other than sponsored result)

I tried if not xxxx then ,still my code prints all here i am attaching my code

[image]

Here is my code

```
Sub Amazon_Pull()
Dim Link_2 As String
 Link_2 = "https://www.amazon.de/s?k=7321925005738&__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss"
 Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument


    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", Link_2, False
        .send
         html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

'Debug.Print html.body.innerHTMLDebug.Print html.getElementsByTagName("div").getAttribute("data-index").Length

Dim hTable As Object
Dim hba As Object



Set hTable = html.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each hba In hTable

  If Left(hba.getAttribute("data-asin"), 1) = "B" Then

     If hba.getElementsByTagName("div")(2).getAttribute("data-component-type") <> "sp-sponsored-result" Then
        Debug.Print hba.getAttribute("data-asin")
     End If

   End If

Next hba


 Set xhr = Nothing
 Set html = Nothing
'-------------
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you are sure about exact HTML elements that determine the sponsored element, I recommend hacking the InnerHTML property of each div and searching for "sp-sponsored-result" (use Like operator or regexp). Not to everybody's taste, but second-guessing external webdevs is notoriously difficult. I would prefer the assumption that if that string of text is in the DIV at all, then it is sponsored.

Answer (score 1):

Use a css attribute = value selector to restrict to the appropriate nodes

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Set nodelist = hba.querySelectorall("[data-asin]")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).getAttribute("data-asin")
Next
```

You can remove your conditional statements and add all the conditional logic into the css selector with starts with ^ operator for the character B

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Set nodelist = hba.querySelectorall("[data-asin^=B]")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).getAttribute("data-asin")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quick and dirty like this. But if the word "Gesponsert" is part of film title, it fails ;-)

```
Sub Amazon_Pull()

Dim Link_2 As String
Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hTable As Object
Dim hba As Object
Dim i As Long

  Link_2 = "https://www.amazon.de/s?k=7321925005738"
  Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

  With xhr
    .Open "GET", Link_2, False
    .send
     html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
  End With

  Set hTable = html.querySelectorAll("div[data-index]")

  For i = 0 To hTable.Length - 1
    If InStr(1, hTable(i).innerText, "Gesponsert") = 0 Then
      Debug.Print hTable(i).getAttribute("data-asin") & " " & hTable(i).getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
    End If
  Next i

  Set xhr = Nothing
  Set html = Nothing
End Sub
```

In my opinion it's always better to use the code structure of a page and not a part of the content. I know, that's not always possible and it's often more complex.

To check if an offer on amazon is sponsored, you can use the structure of the page code like this. One advantage is that it also works on the international Amazon platforms, regardless of the national language.
(Not tested, because Amazon blocked me as a bot.)

```
Sub Amazon_Pull()

Dim Link_2 As String
Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hTable As Object
Dim hba As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim check As Long
Dim sponsored As Boolean
Dim checkSponsored As Object

  Link_2 = "https://www.amazon.de/s?k=7321925005738"
  'Link_2 = "https://www.amazon.de/s?k=apple"
  Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

  With xhr
    .Open "GET", Link_2, False
    .send
     html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
  End With

  Set hTable = html.querySelectorAll("div[data-index]")

  For i = 0 To hTable.Length - 1
    sponsored = False
    Set checkSponsored = hTable(i).querySelectorAll("div[data-component-type]")

    For check = 0 To checkSponsored.Length - 1
      If checkSponsored.getAttribute("data-component-type") = "sp-sponsored-result" Then
        sponsored = True
      End If
    Next check

    If Not sponsored Then
      Debug.Print hTable(i).getAttribute("data-asin") & " " & hTable(i).getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
    End If
  Next i

  Set xhr = Nothing
  Set html = Nothing
End Sub
```